# Why does the tag matching algorithm hide some frequently used tags?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Let's say I want to tag a question "sql-server-2008" on stack overflow.

There are 823 questions tagged Sql-server-2008 but, the tag matching engine won't find it even if I type in:

> Sql-server-200

Why does the tag matching algorithm hide this tag? I guess it's because there's another tag starting with the same string and with a higher count, but still, I think this could use some tweaking ...

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Reproducible with Firefox 3.5.3 and Opera 10. With IE 7 the issue shows up slightly different, but is still there (After `sql-server-` 2008 tag is available but no `sql-server-2008-` tags).

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot reproduce, either on the \tags page or the \ask page.

http://img182.imageshack.us/img182/1127/soask.png

I get the expected partial matches when I type "sql-server-200" (without the quotes) in either box.

EDIT: apparently we neglected to turn off caching for the autocomplete plugin. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I've just reproduced it at home (on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) : "sql-server-200" (without quotes) returns me a single match (ie sql-server-2005). I'm using Firefox 3.5.3 aswell

Comment: no repro, see screenshot

Comment: it works (and my comment is long enough)!

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this on the ask page using FF3.5.3.

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4648/tag1b.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/4648/tag1b.jpg)

Interestingly, if I go back to the start of the string and delete the initial 's', the expected matches come up.

[alt text http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7907/tag2j.jpg](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/7907/tag2j.jpg)

Comment: ok, but how? I can't repro it. Typing speed? mouse vs keyboard? No idea.

Comment: Just using keyboard, typing speed doesn't seem to make any difference. If you type the *entire* name of a tag, the autocomplete can find it, and if you delete the initial portion, it will match on the middle part of the string, e.g. `l-server-200` works just fine. Also, if you provide `sql-server-2008`, then it finds that tag and `sql-server-2008-express` and `sql-server-2008-r2` as well.  Let me know if there's any more detail I can provide.

Comment: Still can't repro, firefox 3.5.3

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?  Maybe your js or ajax response is cached.

Comment: ok, we neglected to turn off caching for the autocomplete plugin. should be fixed now.

Comment: Confirmed fixed. :)